# Sum of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^{-i} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

How is the following sum computed?

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^{-i} $$

Comment: It's a geometric series.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{9^{-i}}{2}$ or $(\frac{9}{2})^{-i}$?

Comment: The second, with parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the formula for a geometric series:

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} kx^n=k\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n=\frac{kx}{1-x}$$

This equality holds for $|x|<1$.

**EDIT**

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^{-i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{i}$$

> Let $x=\frac{2}{9}$ and $k=1$.

Comment: What happens to the 0 term in the sequence?

Comment: Notice that the lower index is $i=1$ and not $i=0$.

Comment: Ok, so I got that by $\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{9}} - 1$.  Is it 2/7?

Comment: Looks correct to me!